# Problem with reinstalling grub2

Tags: grub2, memtest

My gui was gone (I turned on my laptop and memtest popped out and was still there forever) so after some searching I understood that I have to reinstall grub2. I downloaded Ubuntu live cd, put it in a usb stick and booted from there. I opened the terminal and I followed [these steps from here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd).

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub

exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt
```

Grub install messages were ok.

I restarted the laptop,change boot priority and ended up in a error `Can't find command 'fwsetup'` ...And I did it again and I saw that after the `grep-update` I came up with a warning

```
Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration done.
```

Is this responsible for that? What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: i have only one partition for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: btw do i have to choose uefi or legacy mode to boot from usb?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The linked question is about repairing Grub in general no matter how it broke. You can select the boot mode in BIOS. Please look it up in the system manual if you don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Install and use Boot-repair from a live session.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: what do you mean with the '' persistence''?

Comment: bro it worked! boot-repair repaired the whole problem! thanks a lot!

Comment: Persistence isn't required. I'll edit your question because otherwise it's correct and helpful.